# How would you organize UI states using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I have an app that is mostly traditional static HTML pages linked via anchor tags, but lately I've been adding more and more dynamic behavior using JS.

I need to "juggle" between numerous UI states in the form of hiding/showing/creating different elements for every "screen". (Let's say homepage and fullpage blog post.)

If I have only 2 states it's pretty easy but complexity arises as more and more "screens" are added.

**The question:**
How would I organize the various UI states so that it is straightforward to switch between?

Comment: use jQuery http://jquery.com/

Comment: I am using jQuery, the problem is not DOM manipulation. Thanks anyway...

Comment: The question is too general. Can you post a bit of your code and tell us exactly what you are aiming at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running into a lot of complexity managing your UI state, it may well be a sign that  app logic is too tightly coupled with UI handling. This is especially noticeable if there are places where you need to inspect the state of the UI to make decisions about how the app logic should react.

As it gets more complex you may want to consider decoupling the UI using some kind of MVC pattern. Or even better, using a pre-rolled framework such as [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Note: [Other](http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/) [frameworks](http://www.faridesign.net/2012/04/20-javascript-frameworks-mvvm-templating-licenses-etc/) [are available](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-javascript-frameworks-worth-checking-out/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use JavaScriptMVC it's a lightweight framework that has had a fair bit of work put into it the past year or so . By having a client side mvc you could set up two different views and alternate between them with ease .

You may also want to look into sproutcore